# Sum of column elements of dictionary values made of lists in Python

Tags: dictionary, python-3.3

I have a dictionary as follows

```
d = {0:[1,2,3], 1:[2,3,4], 2:[3,4,5], 3:[4,5,6]}
```

What wold be the most compact form in Python to sum the same column elements of the dictionary values which are lists or how can I get the following result out of dictionary values ?

```
[(1+2+3+4), (2+3+4+5), (3+4+5+6)]=[10,14,18]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without NumPy

```
>>> d
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4, 5, 6]}
>>> map(sum, zip(*d.values()))
[10, 14, 18]
```

with NumPy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4, 5, 6]}
>>> map(np.sum, zip(*d.values()))
[10, 14, 18]
```